# Angular table loading spinner on table columns visibility change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have quite big table with many columns. Many columns have attribute "ng-show". Also i have created a functionality which hides or displays some table columns (with "ng-show").

When i trying to apply table columns visibility change ir takes 2-3 seconds for angular to update the table. Is it possible to add loading spinner on the table while it happens?

Simplified table structure:

```
    <table class="classesList" id="tableId">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-show="tableColumns[0].show" >
            <span>Header1</span>
        </th>
        <th ng-show="tableColumns[1].show" >
            <span>Header1</span>
        </th>
        <th ng-show="tableColumns[2].show" >
            <span>Header1</span>
        </th>

        ...
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-show="tableColumns[0].show">
            <span>Data1</span>
        </td>
        <td ng-show="tableColumns[1].show">
            <span>Data2</span>
        </td>
        <td ng-show="tableColumns[2].show">
            <span>Data3</span>
        </td>

        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: yes it's possible.can you post your code example

Comment: Added table code sample. I am updating tableColumns['Nr'].show values in angular.

Comment: Please add your js code with the function or better -  add jsfiddle example

Comment: I have array "tableColumns" = [{show: true}, {show:false}, ...] and function just updates true false values in array and after such update angular updates table in couple seconds.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for - [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t9zygmg1/)

Comment: Not exactly erani_246 your example just delays table render for 2 seconds.

Comment: I know @CroMagnon i do it on purpose. If you will remove the timeout it works and you will not be able to see the spinner because it's very fast.